# Can I connect a stabilizer to an inverter?

Tags: electrical

At my place the voltage in winter is around 140-160V where normally it should be above 200V.
Now I have an inverter at home. The inverter during power shut down turns to batteries and supply 230V of power. But when the mains are on (160V) the inverter gives the output of same 160V as the mains. 
Now I have a question. Can I connect a stabilizer on my inverter so that a continuous voltage of 230V can be supplied to my TV and PS3 and other speakers?

During mains on: 
Mains(160V) > inverter (160V) > stabilizer > 230V

During mains off: 
Mains(0V) > inverter (230V) > stabilizer (230V)

Will this work or damage the inverter? 
Inverter is around 850 VA or KVA something.

I'm from Srinagar, india

Comment: I would recommend looking into getting a full-time UPS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but the order should be- mains to stabilizer to inverter. This way the inverter input would receive 220-240 volts. Apart from giving you good output voltage during mains on, this arrangement would also charge your batteries faster. Make sure to buy a good stabilizer with twice the wattage of your inverter. A 2 KVA Godrej or Vguard stabilizer would do fine. I have been using 3 inverters with this arrangement for 10+ years with no issues. But never connect a stabilizer to the output of your inverter as this may damage your inverter.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the other answer.  The inverter is designed to match the voltage and phase of the mains.  If you try to make it produce a higher voltage, you will be asking it to drive the rest of the city's supply.  You will damage it, and it is unsafe and dangerous.

To do this safely, you need to disconnect the grid.

Or buy a battery management unit.  These come with multiple ports.  So you can connect the grid on one input, the inverter on another and drive the load from the output.  The BMU should disconnect the grid as you set it up.